# How to configure index in model for Algolia search Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I'm having a mini website with Algolia search, I want to search for item in Model 'Item' (means a table names 'item'). This is my code in Controller:

```
    public function search(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->only(['query']);

    $items = Item::search($query['query'])->paginate(12);
    $total = $items->count();

    return view('shop.search', [
        'items'      => $items,
        'total'      => $total,
    ]);
}
```

I was able to search after run the following code:

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Item"
```

and then, It work fine. But when I insert a new Item, I cannot search for that new Item. I have tried this code to configure "Index" (I think it can help) but it always show error :(

```
 public function searchableAs()
{
    return 'posts_index';
}
```

And the error is:

```
Index posts_index does not exist
```

or

```
indexName is not valid
```

Can I have any way to configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`searchableAs` defines your index name in Algolia. At this point, you imported your data in the `items` index, and you are searching in `posts_index`. That's why you get this error.
You need to either remove the `searchableAs` override or reimport the data.

About the data not being updated, it could be that:

- You are using the queue
- You are updating data without Eloquent

If you run `$item->update()` it will update Algolia. If you do `Item::update(['title' => 'new title'])`, you will need to chain the `searchable()` method.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout#updating-records

Comment: Thanks, I will try it again ;D

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Model Indexes

Each Eloquent model is synced with a given search "index", which contains all of the searchable records for that model. In other words, you can think of each index like a MySQL table. By default, each model will be persisted to an index matching the model's typical "table" name. Typically, this is the plural form of the model name; however, you are free to customize the model's index by overriding the searchableAs method on the model:

```
<?php

        namespace App;

        use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

        class Post extends Model
        {
               use Searchable;

               /**
               * Get the index name for the model.
               *
               * @return string
               */
               public function searchableAs()
              {
                      return 'posts_index';
              }
 }
```

Algolia new index create "posts_index" and try it